# What is the right host url in sonar for bamboo(plugin) configuration?

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo

I have to set host url in `sonar for bamboo`(bambo plugin) configuration.
While my local docker program is running sonarqube container, it is confused to use `localhost:9000` at `host url` in app configuration.
The error message is saying `An error occurred while connecting the given SonarQube server: localhost:9000 failed to respond`.

What should I do? Am I doing wrong or Is there anything to set more thing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxOkQ.png)

Comment: The Bamboo server is running in a different server that your Docker container SonarQube?

Comment: Oh... maybe that would be a great hint. Yes, the bamboo server is running in another window server so the `localhost:9000` would not be able to be used.

Answer (score 0):

As your SonarQube instance is running in a different server, you need to point your "Sonar for Bamboo" plugin to that server, port 9000 (default of SonarQube). So, for example, if your server containing the SonarQube instance has the IP address 192.168.15.1 in your network, you need to configure the plugin to http://192.168.15.1:9000.
I did it in my environment and it works perfectly.